# Kendo Grid configured to use HttpPost, but sends a HttpGet request to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a Kendo MVC Grid configured to do a Post, however, the request doesn't reach my action and in the profiler I can see it did a Get request.

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

**View**

```
<script>
  function additionalData() {
    return { code: '@Session.GetCode()' }
  }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Type);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Count);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Date);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(10))
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r.Action("GetGridData", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("additionalData"))
        .PageSize(25)
    )
)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetGridData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string code = "")
{
    var result = MyService.GetGridData(regionCode);
    return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

This is the request as seen in the Internet Explorer 11 debugger, resulting in a 404 error:

[image: Request]

Comment: without this code `.Type(HttpVerbs.Post)` when you add `Data()` after datasource read action method kendo automatically change the request to type POST.. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried `r.Action("GetGridData", "Home", new { code: @Session.GetCode() })` as well, but that had the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to resolve my issue and it's quite silly...

One of the JavaScript files in the solution contained the following code:

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxSend: function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
        if ((settings.type = 'GET')) {

        }
    }
});
```

Just an empty `ajaxSend` catching all my AJAX requests and changing them into GET. Someone was working on this, forgot to remove this bit and checked it in.